# Mail not sending on Vesta and Cloudflare

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mail-server, roundcube, vesta

I am hosting my website on Google Cloud Platform. Every thing is fine but Webmail brings a problem.

When trying to send email it says mail sent successfully but not receiving at delivery address. I am using Roundcube web mail.

Comment: How are you sending the email? Do you have you SMTP server logs to show the email was accepted?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the webmail front-end is successfully submitting the mail to the underlying mail server (hence the success message), but that underlying mail server is not able to deliver the mail.

This is probably because [you can't send email directly from Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/).